# Ember.js - Duplicate record in Store that clears after refresh

Tags: ember.js

I have a basic Rest API and when I visit my newPost page, there is a form I can fill in with 'title' and 'text' fields as well as a submit button. After I create the record, I save it with the controller and transitionToRoute('posts').

When I view the 'posts' page, the input I just entered is displayed twice. I checked the Ember inspector and it looks like the record is put into the data store twice, once as I click the create button and one after the page refreshes. When I refresh the browser again, the duplicate is removed.

How do I get rid of the duplicate record in the store? Cheers for any suggestions.

EDIT: I believe I have solved my issue by using a filter to remove posts that hadn't been persisted yet.

Updated Routes:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  },

  setupController: function() {
    var posts = this.store.filter('post', function (post) {
      return !post.get('isDirty');
    });

    this.controllerFor('posts').set('model', posts);
  } 
});

App.NewPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('post');
  }
});
```

Routes:

```
/* Routes */
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('newPost');
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  },

  setupController: function() {
    var posts = this.store.filter('post', function (post) {
      return !post.get('isDirty');
    });

    this.controllerFor('posts').set('model', posts);
  } 
});

App.NewPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('post');
  }
});
```

NewPostController:

```
actions:
  createPost: function() {
    ...
    var post = this.get('store').createRecord('post', {
      title: title,
      text: text
    });

    this.set('title', '');
    this.set('text', '');

    post.save();
    this.transitionToRoute('posts');
    ...
  newRecord: function() {
    this.set('content', App.Post);
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: A fiddle would help. Also why are you setting the model to `App.Post`?

Comment: @PanagiotisPanagi Hey, I posted my code to a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/songawee/4nB8x/ Also, I set the model to App.Post because the variables weren't binding to the form inputs. I guess my intention was to provide a post model for the inputs of the form to bind to. Any suggestions? Thanks for you help.

Comment: App.Post is the class. You should create an instance of App.Post. See http://jsfiddle.net/4nB8x/1/

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. In the NewPostController, would you recommend saving the post a different way? I seem to still be getting the two responses.

Comment: @PanagiotisPanagi Hey! I think I figured it out. I added a filter for the posts route that only looks for records that are not dirty. I updated the fiddle if you want to check it out. Thanks again for your help though!

Comment: @songawee could you explain me more.. me too facing the same problem, where you have included the filter in that fiddle?

Comment: @Abhiram The issue I was having was after I would create a new record. There would be a "dirty" and non-dirty record and they would both show up and you would see a duplicate entry until you refreshed the page. I created the filter as shown on line 38 of this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4nB8x/4/. This only shows one of the created records.

Comment: ya ok now i got it.. thanks for your reply..